# How to calculate sum previous payment?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a dataset with columns user_id, type and purchase:

[image]

I want to calculate maximum sum previous payment.

Example tables:

| user_id | type | purchase | prev_payment |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | request | 12362 | NA |
| 1 | request | 32543 | NA |
| 1 | request | 23413 | NA |
| 1 | request | 12344 | NA |
| 1 | payment | 15316 | NA |
| 1 | request | 32252 | 15316 |
| 1 | request | 34531 | 15316 |
| 1 | payment | 32536 | 15316 |
| 1 | request | 2343256 | 32536 |
| 1 | request | 234323 | 32536 |

```
data = [[1, 'request', 12362], [1, 'request', 32543], [1, 'request', 23413], [1, 'request', 12344], [1, 'payment', 15316],
 [1, 'request', 32252], [1, 'request', 34531], [1, 'payment', 32536], [1, 'request', 2343256], [1, 'request', 234323]]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['user_id', 'type', 'purchase'])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can mask your data to keep only the "payment" rows, then `shift` and `ffill`:

```
df['prev_payment'] = df['purchase'].where(df['type'].eq('payment')).shift().ffill()
```

output:

```
      type  purchase  prev_payment
0  request     12362           NaN
1  request     32543           NaN
2  request     23413           NaN
3  request     12344           NaN
4  payment     15316           NaN
5  request     32252       15316.0
6  request     34531       15316.0
7  payment     32536       15316.0
8  request   2343256       32536.0
9  request    234323       32536.0
```

###### per group:

```
df['prev_payment'] = (df['purchase']
                      .where(df['type'].eq('payment'))
                      .groupby(df['user_id'])
                      .apply(lambda s: s.shift().ffill())
                     )
```

Comment: Sorry, Initially, there was a little wrong condition. Now corrected it. Need groupby on user_id and fill max purchase.